# "rejected promise not handled within 1 second" vscode API

Tags: javascript, api, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I have been working on my first vscode extension and all has gone well until the debugger would stop my the execution of my extension.

I am fairly new to javascript so maybe I am missing something on "thenables" but here is my problem.

I run my extension using keyboard shortcuts eg. "**ctrl + alt + o**" and it runs fine, but the moment I change "**activeTextEditor**" I get "***rejected promise not handled within 1 second***" in my debug console.

The suspected section is this:

```
    const checkOutHeader = (history) => {
    console.log("Path: checkOutHeader");
    activeTextEditor.edit((editor) => {
        editor.replace(new vscode.Range(0,0,10,100), commentHeader(
            populateCheckOutHeader(head.out, history).substring(1), languageId));
    }).then((none)=>{
        console.log("We are here!");
        saveFile();
    });
};
```

This is based of the path my extension logged in the debug console:

```
CheckoutHeader: Now active!
Path: getHeaderConfig
lang: makefile
Path: supportHeaderLanguage
Path: checkInHandler
Path: getCurrentHeader
Path: getHistoryFileStatus
Path: getHeaderHistory
Path: getHistoryFileName
Path: getHistoryFileStatus
Path: getHistoryTimeIn
Path: getHistoryInBy
Path: getHistoryTimeOut
Path: getHistoryOutBy
Path: checkInHeader
rejected promise not handled within 1 second
```

I have read that some people claimed it was c++tools but I do not have that extension installed.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need `catch((e) => ` after `then(`.

Comment: Which promise is getting rejected and with what error message?

Comment: @jcbuic I have tried that but it did not seem to work.

Comment: @Bergi I have no idea it only says "rejected promise not handled within 1 second"

Comment: @CorryTerblanche Oh. You should report that as a bug of the environement, it should always report the error as well.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for the advice, I spent some time looking for answers and saw that quite a few people where having this issue, where it gets this error randomly, many have reported it already. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that the promise was never the problem despite the debug feedback.

I had set global variables in the top of my file

```
const activeTextEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
const document = activeTextEditor.document;
const languageId = document.languageId;
```

to make accessing the API's more convenient, but as a result of them only being initiated when I run the extension the first time whenever I would change the "**activeTextEditor**" the variable would still contain old information causing the crash..